# RxJava2/RxAndroidBle: subscribe to Observable from side effects

Tags: rx-java2, rxandroidble

I have the following use case of a simple BLE device setup process using `RxAndroidBle`:

1. Connect to a BLE device.
2. Start listening to notification characteristic and set up a parser to parse each incoming notification. Parser will then use a `PublishSubject` to publish parsed data.
3. Perform a write to write characteristic (negotiate secure connection).
4. Wait for parser `PublishSubject` to deliver the parsed response from device - public key (which arrived through the notification characteristic as a response to our write).
5. Perform another write to the write characteristic (set connection as secure).
6. Deliver a `Completable` saying if the process has completed successfully or not.

Right now my solution (not working) looks like this:

```
deviceService.connectToDevice(macAddress)
    .andThen(Completable.defer { deviceService.setupCharacteristicNotification() })
    .andThen(Completable.defer { deviceService.postNegotiateSecurity() })
    .andThen(Completable.defer {
        parser.notificationResultSubject
            .flatMapCompletable { result ->
                when (result) {
                    DevicePublicKeyReceived -> Completable.complete()
                    else -> Completable.error(Exception("Unexpected notification parse result: ${result::class}"))
                }
            }
    })
    .andThen(Completable.defer { deviceService.postSetSecurity() })
```

And the `DeviceService` class:

```
class DeviceService {

    /**
     * Observable keeping shared RxBleConnection for reuse by different calls
     */
    private var connectionObservable: Observable<RxBleConnection>? = null

    fun connectToDevice(macAddress: String): Completable {
        return Completable.fromAction {
            connectionObservable = 
                rxBleClient.getBleDevice(macAddress)
                .establishConnection(false) 
                .compose(ReplayingShare.instance())
        }
    }

   fun setupCharacteristicNotification(): Completable =
        connectionObservable?.let {
            it
                .switchMap { connection ->
                    connection.setupNotification(UUID_NOTIFICATION_CHARACTERISTIC)
                        .map { notificationObservable -> notificationObservable.doOnNext { bytes -> parser.parse(bytes) }.ignoreElements() }
                        .map { channel ->
                            Observable.merge(
                                Observable.never<RxBleConnection>().startWith(connection),
                                channel.toObservable()
                            )
                        }
                        .ignoreElements()
                        .toObservable<RxBleConnection>()
                }
                .doOnError { Timber.e(it, "setup characteristic") }
                .take(1).ignoreElements()
        } ?: Completable.error(CONNECTION_NOT_INITIALIZED)

   fun postNegotiateSecurity(): Completable {
        val postLength = negotiateSecurity.postNegotiateSecurityLength()
        val postPGK = negotiateSecurity.postNegotiateSecurityPGKData()

        return connectionObservable?.let {
            it.take(1)
                .flatMapCompletable { connection ->
                    postLength
                        .flatMapSingle { connection.write(it.bytes.toByteArray()) }
                        .doOnError { Timber.e(it, "post length") }
                        .flatMap {
                            postPGK
                                .flatMapSingle { connection.write(it.bytes.toByteArray()) }
                                .doOnError { Timber.e(it, "post PGK") }
                        }
                        .take(1).ignoreElements()
                }
        } ?: Completable.error(CONNECTION_NOT_INITIALIZED)
    }

    fun postSetSecurity(): Completable =
        connectionObservable?.let {
            it.take(1)
                .flatMapCompletable { connection ->
                    negotiateSecurity.postSetSecurity()
                        .flatMapSingle { connection.write(it.bytes.toByteArray()) }
                        .take(1).ignoreElements()
                }
        } ?: Completable.error(CONNECTION_NOT_INITIALIZED)
   }

private fun RxBleConnection.write(bytes: ByteArray): Single<ByteArray> =
    writeCharacteristic(UUID_WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC, bytes)
```

The problem is that it gets stuck in `deviceService.postNegotiateSecurity()` and never gets past. I don't get any data in the parser as well, so I assume I'm incorrectly subscribing to the notification characteristic.

`negotiateSecurity.postNegotiateSecurityLength()` and `negotiateSecurity.postNegotiateSecurityPGKData()` are methods which prepare data to be sent and deliver it as `Observable<SendFragment>`. Because of data frame size limit, one frame might be encoded as several fragments, which are then emitted by these `Observable`s.

Answer (score 0):

#### Recap:

- `postNegotiateSecurity()` is never completed
- `negotiateSecurity.postNegotiateSecurityLength()` may emit one or more times
- `negotiateSecurity.postNegotiateSecurityPGKData()` may emit one or more times

#### Analysis (omitted logs for readability):

```
it.take(1)
    .flatMapCompletable { connection ->
        postLength
            .flatMapSingle { connection.write(it.bytes.toByteArray()) }
            .flatMap {
                postPGK // may emit more than one value
                    .flatMapSingle { connection.write(it.bytes.toByteArray()) }
            }
            .take(1) // first emission from the above `flatMap` will finish the upstream
            .ignoreElements()
    }
```

Every emission from `postLength` will start a characteristic write. Every succeeded write will start subscription to `postPGK`. If `postLength` will emit more than once — more subscriptions to `postPGK` will be made.

Every subscription to `postPGK` most likely will result in multiple emissions. Every emission will then be flatMapped to a characteristic write. Every write succeeded write will emit a value.

After the first emission from the above mentioned characteristic write the upstream will be disposed (because of `.take(1)` operator).

If the `postNegotiateSecurity()` is actually started it will also finish or error (given that both `postLength` and `postPGK` will emit at least one value) since there is no additional logic here.

#### Conclusion

`postNegotiateSecurity()` will most probably complete (but not in an intended manner) as the first packet from `postPGK` will finish it. I would assume that the peripheral expects full data before it will notify anything therefore it is waiting for the PGK to be fully transmitted which will not happen as shown above.

Logs from the application with `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)` set on could help with understanding of what actually happened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It turned out the main culprit was `take(1)`, which interrupted the connection. There were some other things wrong with my architecture here as well.